# Combine two queries to check for duplicates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Number  | Name 
--------+--------
123     | Robert
```

This is what I want to do:

If the Number is already in the database, don't insert a new record.

If the Number is not in the databse, but the name is, create a new name and insert it.  So for example, if I have a record that contains `123` for `Number` and `Bob` for `Name`, I don't want to insert it, but if I get a record that contains `456` for `Number` and `Robert` for `name`, I would insert `456` and `Robert1`.  I was going to check for duplicates individually like:

```
SELECT * FROM Person where Number = 123;

//If number is not found
SELECT * FROM Person where Name = 'Robert';

//If name is found, add a number to it.
```

Is there a way I can combine the two statements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually two problems in your question. The first problem is to make `Number` column unique and the second one is to increment the column `Name` by appending a number if it already exists.

**FIRST PART**

Since the number is `UNIQUE`, enforce a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column. It could be a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE KEY`.

If the column has no `KEY` and you want to make it `PRIMARY`, here is the `ALTER` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (Number)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/843a3/1)

but if you only want it to be `UNIQUE` and not a primary key,

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Number)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2bf6/1)

**SECOND PART**

You can actually do it without using join.

```
INSERT INTO TableName(Number, Name)
SELECT  124 AS Number, 
        CONCAT('Robert', COALESCE(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(Name, 'Robert', '0') AS UNSIGNED)) + 1,'')) AS Name
FROM    TableName
WHERE   Name LIKE 'Robert%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/961d56/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added more example*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c72d6/9)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*throws exception due to uniqueness*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74f2c)

Some details:

when the value supplied on column `Number` already exists, it will throw an error since the column is unique. I have read a comment from a deleted posts saying: *"..Number is not unique, but if it does exist, I don't want to enter a record."* -- it does not make any sense if you don't want to add *uniqueness* on the column. How will you know if the number already exists or not? Doing a little check for the existence of `Number` feels like a little overhead for me. So my best recommendation is to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: @J.W. at least give us **some time** to think :P, because your answer are so Perfect that we can't think any other better answer. In between let me connect with you **F.B.** :)

Comment: When i insert `Rober` instead of `Robert`, your query results error: `Data truncation: Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '0t' `, while Rober is new Name and valid.

Comment: second part is really amazing :) +1

Comment: just one minor thing... i think you should use `WHERE Name RLIKE '^Robert[0-9]*$'` or something like this

Comment: Assume i first inserted a row with Name:`abab` in the table. after it when i insert `ab` , your query will insert actually `ab1` instead of `ab`, while `ab` is not exists in the table before.

Comment: @fthiella you're right! i just tested your suggestion and it totally worked! http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c0b5/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Number = 123 OR Name = 'Robert'
```

I haven't worked with SQL for some time, so this may be wrong ;)

Edit:

```
$number = 123;
$name = 'Robert';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Number = $number OR Name = '$name' ");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0 ) {
//-> Add your record, it's unused
} else if (mysql_result($query, 0, 'number') == $number && mysql_result($query, 0, 'name' == $name)) {
//combination of number and name already exists -> modify name and add record
} else {
echo "Number is used by another name";
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to only return it if an only if the Number does not exist, basically I don't want to do an OR, but I still want to get the Name even if the Number does not exist, so if I do a query like `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Number = 123 AND Name = 'Bob'`, this would return nothing, but I don't want that, I want to still return a record with the Name.

Comment: I think that this does what you want. $number = 123;
$name = 'Robert';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Number = $number OR Name = '$name' ");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0 ) {
//-> Add your record, it's unused
} else {
if (mysql_result($query, 0, 'number') == $number && mysql_result($query, 0, 'name' == $name)) {
//combination of number and name already exists -> modify name and add record
} else {
echo "Number is used by another name";
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Use this query, for insert the row `[123, 'Robert']`. if you want insert other values, change `123` & `Robert` values in below query:

```
insert into Person (Number,Name)
select 123, IF(mn.MaxNumber is NULL,'Robert',concat('Robert',mn.MaxNumber+1))
from (SELECT 'foo') foo
left JOIN (select max(CONVERT(SUBSTR(Name,LENGTH('Robert')+1),UNSIGNED)) `MaxNumber`
            from person where name rlike '^Robert[0-9]*$') mn on 1=1
where Not Exists (select * from Person where Number=123)
```

*NOTE*: if `Robert` exists in the table, above query inserts `Robert1`. if `Robert1` exists, it inserts `Robert2`, and so on .

Comment: *"I Think my answer is best, so i give the bounty to myself."* -- a deleted answer of yours. did you think about the performance?

Comment: @JW웃, My answer is suitable for when we dont want to enforce a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column. Because the Questioner @Xaisoft, didnt say about `UNIQUE` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

make both number and name unique.

```
   ALTER TABLE  `person` ADD UNIQUE (`number` ,`name`);
```

You can now do a insert with ON DUPLICATE

```
INSERT INTO `person` (`number`, `name`, `id`) VALUES ('322', 'robert', 'NULL')       ON DUPLICATE  KEY UPDATE `id`='NULL';
```

For appending a number after name i would suggest using autoincrement column instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Person (Number,Name)
select 123, IF(mn.MaxNumber is NULL,'Robert',concat('Robert',mn.MaxNumber+1))
from (SELECT 'foo') foo
left JOIN (select max(CONVERT(SUBSTR(Name,LENGTH('Robert')+1),UNSIGNED)) `MaxNumber`
            from person where name rlike '^Robert[0-9]*$') mn on true
where Not Exists (select * from Person where Number=123)
```