# How can I add "ID" or "count number" after the "mysql repetitive values"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big database and there are so many **repetitive values on NAME table.** It is impossible to update them manually. I tried to make a programme for adding ID's last of values and make the table unique but i failed.

How can I update them with php or mysql?

That is an example of a table includes repetitive values.
**There are 4 alex, 2 shama and 1 jenny names.**

```
| ID | NAME     |
|  1 | alex     |
|  2 | alex     |
|  3 | shama    |
|  4 | jenny    |
|  5 | alex     |
|  6 | shama    |
|  7 | alex     |
```

**and that is what i want to make.**

**That includes ID with dot after the repetitive names**

```
| ID | NAME     |
|  1 | alex     |
|  2 | alex.2   |
|  3 | shama    |
|  4 | jenny    |
|  5 | alex.3   |
|  6 | shama.2  |
|  7 | alex.4   |
```

Comment: bad idea, use the id column

Comment: don't do this. forcing pepole to change their names because someone else has that same name is a failure of **YOUR** system. you've already got a unique ID for every name. use that.

Comment: And why would you not change `alex` on the row with id = 5?

Comment: for example 
alex@xxx.com 
alex.2@xxx.com
by this reason I have to make the names unique.

Comment: so then `select id,name` and use `$name.$id@xxx.com` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table does not contain names that ends with dot+a number already, you could use this UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE
  names INNER JOIN
  (SELECT   n1.id, n1.name, count(n2.id)+1 cnt
   FROM     names n1 INNER JOIN names n2
            ON n1.name=n2.name AND n1.id>n2.id
   GROUP BY n1.id, n1.name) s
  ON names.id = s.id
SET
  names.name = CONCAT(names.name, '.', s.cnt)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b95bc5/1).

**Edit**

As stated above, this solution will only work if there are no records that ends already with a dot and a digit, for example if you have these records, it will fail:

```
alex
alex
alex.2
```

and also, you can use this solution to fix your records **only once**. If you need to insert new records you can't launch again this query but you should use an INSERT query like this:

```
INSERT INTO names (ID, Name)
SELECT  8,
        CONCAT('alex.',
          COALESCE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(Name, LENGTH('alex.')+1, 1) AS UNSIGNED)) + 1,'')
        ) AS Name
FROM    names
WHERE   Name RLIKE '^alex\.[0-9]*$'
```

(which is a slighyly modified and fixed query taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509540/833073)).

Even if this makes things a little more complicated, I think it is much better to calculate a counter rather than exposing an internal ID (an account named `alex.2` looks much better than an account named `alex.78964` ...).

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7459b/1).

Comment: It is great job. I tried to make it 7-8 hours but i failed. Than you so much. I chouldnt vote you. I am starter

Comment: @Andrew please don't do this, you will regret it.

Comment: 5 minutes ago my reputation was 1. I found a way to make it 15 and i can vote now and i did. what do you mean?

Comment: @downvoters why a downvote? it's very common to use something like this for account names, e-mails, etc. I prefer to use $name.$counter@xxx.com rather than $name.$id@xxx.com, but that's up to the OP... but i think the answer is correct.

Comment: @Andrew you can also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449377/combine-two-queries-to-check-for-duplicates-in-mysql it might help you if you need to add more names once the table is fixed

Comment: @Dagon why you say not to do this?

Comment: next time an alex joins you will have to do a new count of alex, no wait that's a count of alex+number, not even alex% will work. but then some people may use the name alex11 in the first place. and that's just one problem.

Comment: @dagon this query is intended to fix an existing situation, I also added a link to a question with an excellent answer that makes inserting new alexes very easily, taking care of everything. I don't want to use an internal id as the name of my users, it might be easier but it just looks bad.

Comment: shama.2 looks better than shama.6 if you say so. and i dont see a solution for people who already call them selves alex99. which is why you use unique ids in the first place